# What permissions are needed to read the privacy status of a Facebook Group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to be able to look up the groups to which users belong to and determine if they are private or public groups, but can't figure out how to do it or if it is possible. Let's say a user logging into my app belongs to this group:

```
{
  "name": "Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency",
  "id": "157119217731253"
}
```

I've tried every `group`-related permission, but I cannot retrieve the `privacy` property (documented here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/group) in order to determine if the group is a closed (private) group or not. How do I find that out?

`157119217731253?fields=privacy`
returns

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "G24ygvXL3F+"
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your link, in the description of the privacy field:

> The privacy setting of the Group. Possible values are CLOSED, OPEN,
>   and SECRET. **Requires an access token of an Admin of the Group**.

...assuming that you do not manage the group in question.